# How to increase the fetching time of a particular value from database from java?

Tags: java, database, performance, time, fetch

I want to fetch a particular value from database in java. I used the following command in prepared statement:

```
Select Pname from table where pid=458;
```

The table contains around 50,000 rows and taking more time to fetch,  please help me to get the data faster.

i used index and then i bind the variable also but it reduce the execution time only few seconds, i need more efficient. Is there any way to retrieve data faster???

Comment: which Database are you using

Comment: I am using SQL server

Answer (score 4):

Index your database table for pid, it will make the search faster.

Indexes are used to quickly locate data without having to search every row in a database table every time a database table is accessed. Indexes can be created using one or more columns of a database table, providing the basis for both rapid random lookups and efficient access of ordered records.

SQL Server

```
CREATE TABLE MyCustomers (CustID int, CompanyName nvarchar(50));

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idxCustId ON MyCustomers (CustId);
```

References

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345331(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: can you share any example??

Comment: @pandian - Please see the example and references.

Comment: i used index and then i bind the variable also but it reduce the execution time only few seconds, i need more efficient. Is there any way to retrieve data faster???

Answer (score 1):

1. Create index on field pid in your table.
2. Use bind variables in queries.

Use prepared statement instead of statement in Java, that will use bind variables.
pstatement = conn.prepareStatement("Select Pname from table where pid = ?");

This ensures that the SQl is pre compiled and hence runs faster.

However, you are likely to gain more performance improvement by index than bind variables .

Comment: Please share the example

Comment: I'm using Oracle DB, but common syntax for creating index is `CREATE INDEX index_name ON your_tbl ( pid ASC )` You better refer to SQL Server documentation. After index creation simply run your query, it should fetch data faster.

Comment: i used index and then i bind the variable also but it reduce the execution time only few seconds, i need more efficient. Is there any way to retrieve data faster???